# odbc32 and SQLBrowseConnect Help

Tags: sql, odbc, smo

I'm making a call to odbc32.dll (SQLBrowseConnect) to return a list of databases on a sql server.

From running a trace I can see the query being executed is

```
select name from master..sysdatabases where has_dbaccess(name)=1
```

If the credentials I pass aren't the sa user it returns just the system databases. Is there anyway I can use SQLBrowseConnect with another user (whose default database is also not guarenteed to be the master database) to return all databases on the server?

Also I want to avoid smo objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query does work without sysadmin credentials.

You need to ensure that you / the credentials you are using are at least in the [public database role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187718.aspx) on each of the databases that you need to connect to.

As you would guess, select name from master..sysdatabases returns all database names irrespective of your access to the DB.